# Custom Annotation not found while unit testing

Tags: java, reflection, junit, annotations

say i've an Annotation like that:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AutoConvert {
    boolean enabled() default true;
}
```

and class annotated with it:

```
@AutoConvert
public class ExampleCommandToExample extends BaseConverter{}
```

On the superclass i'am doing the following:

```
public void convert(){
  Annotation annotation = (AutoConvert) this.getClass().getAnnotation(AutoConvert.class);
}
```

Everything works fine on runtime! Annotation is getting found and properly set!

But! While unit testing the convert method with JUnit:
this.getClass().getAnnotation(AutoConvert.class) 
**always returns null.**

The test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void convertTest(){
    //when
    exampleCommandToExample.convert();
}
```

Are custom annotations not being found by reflection while running unit tests?
Does anyone has an answer for me?
I would really really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
Alright it seems to be grounded in the kind of intatiation...
I do the following:

```
exampleCommandToExample = new ExampleCommandToExample() {
    @Override
    public Type overideSomeMethod() {
        return type;
    }
};
```

May it be possible that an instance looses all it's annotations 
if I override some methods on instantiation?

Comment: Please provide more details about your tests configuration and how `exampleCommandToExample` is instantiated in `convertTest`. I have tried to reproduce using the current description and the annotation has been found without problems.

Comment: thanks to you antot! You brought me to this. it seems the annotations get lost if I instantiate the class anonymously in order to override some methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `exampleCommandToExample` ref represents an instance of an anonymous class, the call `this.getClass().getAnnotation(AutoConvert.class)` collects the annotations at its level and all inherited ones.

However, `@AutoConvert` in this example of anonymous implementation is not inherited, that is why `getAnnotation` returns `null`, which corresponds exactly to the behavior declared in [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-):

> Returns this element's annotation for the specified type if such an annotation is present, else null.

To solve the issue, simply add

```
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface AutoConvert { /* no changes */ }
```

`@Inherited` will make the annotation visible for the anonymous implementation.